# Montgomery multiplication without final subtraction

Tags: modular-arithmetic, montgomery-multiplication

I am looking for methods to avoid the final subtraction in Montgomery multiplication. I found this paper "A Cryptographic Library for the Motorola DSP56000 " (http://goo.gl/DHePEx) In this paper they have said that we can avoid final subtraction if we keep N(modulus)

Comment: Did you check Gaël Hachez and Jean-Jacques Quisquater, *Montgomery Exponentiation with no Final Subtractions: Improved Results*. In Cryptographic Hardware and Embedded Systems - CHES 2000, LNCS 1965, pp. 293-301, Springer,  2000.  http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44499-8_23

Answer (score 2):

Brett just asked & answered this question : [Confused about final subtraction of modulus in Montgomery Multiplication, during modular exponentiation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/confused-about-final-subtraction-of-modulus-in-montgomery-multiplication-during?rq=1)

You should increase $R$ exponent by $2$.
If you use $n=1024$ , increase it to be $$n=1024 + 2 = 1026.$$
Recalculate the pre-compute $R'$, based on the new exponent.
$$R' = 2^{(2\cdot 1026)} \bmod(M).$$

Comment: We have $LaTeX$/MathJax enabled in this site. Please check my edits.

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned work is focused on a hardware implementation (I have this work as a PDF). I'd suggest you to search for:

17. Colin D. Walter. Montgomery Exponentiation Needs no Final Subtractions. Electronics
    Letters, 35(21):1831{1832, October 1999.
18. Colin D. Walter. Montgomery's Multiplication Technique: How to Make It Smaller
    and Faster. In C etin K. Koc and Christof Paar, editors, Cryptographic Hardware
    and Embedded Systems - CHES '99, volume 1717 of LNCS, pages 80{93. Springer-
    Verlag, August 1999.

Those I don't have and never tried to find.

---

Montgomery Exponentiation with no Final
Subtractions: Improved Results
Gael Hachez and Jean-Jacques Quisquater

Abstract. The Montgomery multiplication is commonly used as the
core algorithm for cryptosystems based on modular arithmetic. With
the advent of new classes of attacks (timing attacks, power attacks), the
implementation of the algorithm should be carefully studied to thwart
those attacks. Recently, Colin D. Walter proposed a constant time implementation
of this algorithm [17, 18]. In this paper, we propose an
improved (faster ) version of this implementation. We also provide gures
about the overhead of these versions relatively to a speed optimised
version (theoretically and experimentally).

Comment: Actually, googling for "Colin D. Walter. Montgomery Exponentiation Needs no Final Subtractions" soon gives you the PDF:      Conclusion 
  We  have  considered  implementations  of  the  RSA  cryptosystem  which  use  solely 
Montgomery’s modular multiplication algorithm and shown  that under standard, easily met, 
inexpensive  conditions,  the  total  encryption  process  never  needs  any  extra  subtractions  to 
produce output in the correct range.